# Is it possible to open Rstudio from right click inside any folder?

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, gnome

I would like to know if there is an option/setup to open rstuio from any directory (similar to "open in terminal" for terminal)?.

Basically, I would like to open rstudio from the working directory (say "A"), complete the required task and close the rstudio so if I again visit "A" folder then I just need to open .RData and check the step which I followed.

Comment: RStudio prefers to do this with .Rproj files. If you create a project file, when you click on it, RStudio will open with the directory where the Rproj file is located as the current working directory.

Comment: Otherwise what operating system are you using?

Comment: @MrFlick it is gnome Linux. Actually, I was thinking to make empty .Rdata and .Rhistory file but again I need to copy & paste them every time in the desired directory. I don't know if it is difficult or impossible, but it would be good if we can workaround for this.

Comment: The question leaves open, what you want to do with RStudio. Chances are, you want to run R and not necessarily RStudio. If so, that might be a lot easier. http://www.cureffi.org/2014/01/15/running-r-batch-mode-linux/